# Problema con Doughnut Chart JS, no es perfectamente circular

Tags: chart.js

Estoy haciendo un gráfico de rosquillas con Chart.JS que se parece al diseño, lo he hecho pero no es un círculo perfecto y es muy triangular. Gracias por su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ```
> const ctxx = document.getElementById('myChartt'); const myChartt = new Chart(ctxx, {
> type: 'doughnut',
> data: {
>     labels: ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We'],
>     datasets: [{
>         label: 'Stock de productos',
>         data: [6, 6, 6],
>         backgroundColor: [
>             'rgba(250, 107, 250)',
>             'rgba(231, 73, 231)',
>             'rgba(202, 65, 202)',
>         ],
>         borderWidth: 0,
>         cutout: '80',
>         borderRadius: 40,
>         offset: -58
>
>     }]
> },
> options: {
>     maintainAspectRatio: false,
>     plugins: {
>         legend: {
>             display: false
>         },
>     }
> } });
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes cambiar offset por spacing y sacar cutout

```js
const ctxx = document.getElementById('myChartt'); 
const myChartt = new Chart(ctxx, {
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
    labels: ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Stock de productos',
        data: [6, 6, 6],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(250, 107, 250)',
            'rgba(231, 73, 231)',
            'rgba(202, 65, 202)',
        ],
         borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 40,
        spacing: -58

    }]
},
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
    }
} });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-ElRFoEQdI5Ht6kZvyzXhYG9NqjtkmlkfYk0wr6wHxU9JEHakS7UJZNeml5ALk+8IKlU6jDgMabC3vkumRokgJA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<canvas id="myChartt"></canvas>
```